# Assigning a delegate function to an EventHandler defined in an interface

Tags: c#, event-handling, delegates, eventhandler

I'm working with an interface `IEventLogWatcher`, its implementation `EventLogWatcherWrapper`, and a class that uses it all `Subscriber`. The issue I'm having revolves around assigning a delegate function to the `EventHandler` inside `EventLogWatcherWrapper`. My goal is to have the `ReadEventLog()` function get called when the `EventRecordWritten` event gets raised:

`IEventLogWatcher.cs`

```
public interface IEventLogWatcher : IDisposable {
    event EventHandler<IEventRecordWrittenEventArgs> EventRecordWritten;
}
```

`EventLogWatcherWrapper.cs`

```
class EventLogWatcherWrapper : IEventLogWatcher {
    private EventLogWatcher eventLogWatcher {get; set;}
    public event EventHandler<IEventRecordWrittenEventArgs> WrapperEventRecordWritten;

    public EventLogWatcherWrapper(EventLogQuery eventQuery){
        eventLogWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(eventQuery);
    }

    event EventHandler<IEventRecordWrittenEventARgs> IEventLogWatcher.EventRecordWritten
    {
        add => WrapperEventRecordWritten += value;
        remove => WrapperEventRecordWritten -= value;
    }
}
```

`Subscriber.cs`

```
public class Subscriber{
    IEventLogWatcher _watcher = new EventLogWatcherWrapper(someEventQuery);
     
    public void someFunction(){
        ...
        _watcher.EventRecordWritten += ReadEventLog;
        // A breakpoint immediately after this statement reveals that _watcher.EventRecordWritten is still null even after this assignment
    }

    public void ReadEventLog(object obj, IEventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg){
        // I expect this to get called when the EventRecordWritten event gets raised.
        // This never gets called.
    }
}
```

For some reason when I assign `_watcher.EventRecordWritten += ReadEventLog;`, I still see null for the `EventRecordWritten` field of `_watcher` so I suspect I am doing something wrong in `EventLogWatcherWrapper` in implementing the interface?

Comment: Do you expect that _watcher is shared between all Subscribers and a potential Publisher existing? Currently everyone has its own Eventlog(Wrapper). So only if a Subscriber triggers this event the same Subscriber could be informed. That doesn't sound to helpful.

Comment: I assume it stays null because it doesn't actually get assigned any subscriber, and instead everything that is "subscribed" to it is being passed to the `WrapperEventRecordWritten` event. Do you really need that custom implementation of the event accessors?

Comment: As for `ReadEventLog` you'll probably have to invoke the `WrapperEventRecordWritten` event for the `ReadEventLog` method to be called

Comment: How do you check for null? I could not reproduce with this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/znZs7y